# MVN Package Build Failure

Tags: java, maven, javac

I am trying to package a java project using maven. I've done it before on my old computer, but I can't seem to make it work on my new computer.

Here is the error:

`

```
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-38-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_95
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $
```

Here is my version information for java, javac and mvn:

```
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-38-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_95
(env)kyle@thinkpad ~/Code/simplefilehosting $
```

I tried looking at it online and add a plugin but then my mvn never realized the plugins tag or anything else. And I haven't changed the pom.xml from the last time I was able to package it.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual error message to diagnose (I think you intended to include it but didn't)...but a few things:

-check your M2_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables and make sure they are correct
-make sure settings.xml is in your ~/.m2 or $M2_HOME/config directories
-on your old machine, delete your entire ~/.m2/repository directory and see if it builds, if you upgraded Maven along the way there might be something you already have that Maven3 can't for some reason download
-consider upgrading, 3.0.5 was an intermediate version that was between the old Maven2 and Maven3 artifact resolution, some major differences, some completely different behavior, who knows what you have.

Comment: crap I just realized I accidentally pasted the same thing. I will change that. After I go through suggestions.